# SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <(...) - dojo/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm using the following AJAX in my project

```
    var _getWeatherInfo = function(ntown){
    //Debugging
    console.log("Before dojo.xhrget");
      //dojo ajax request used to call the PHP file and retrieve the towns data
      dojo.xhrGet({
          handleAs: "json",
          timeout: 5000,
          //php file URL (location)
          url: "PHP/weather.php?ntown=" + ntown,

          load: function(results) {
              //send the results to the function _refreshWeatherList
              _refreshWeatherList(results);               
        }

    });
    //Debugging
    console.log("After dojo.xhrget");
}
```

In order to retrieve weather data for cities/towns. However, its been a while since i worked on this project and i'm having trouble understanding why this is no longer working (it was working last time i ran this project).

In the browser console im getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.b.fromJson (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:227:426)
    at Object.b._contentHandlers.b.contentHandlers.json (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:185:216)
    at t (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:189:392)
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:75:221)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:75:10)
    at resolve.callback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:76:350)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:192:378
    at k (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:196:406)
    at n (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:196:332)
    at resolve (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js:198:406)y @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14021(anonymous function) @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:13981c @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4579d @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4560reject.errback @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4655c @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4594d @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4560reject.errback @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4655c @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4590d @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4560resolve.callback @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:4640(anonymous function) @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14208k @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14488n @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14479resolve @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14643a @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14532k @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14503n @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14479resolve @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14643a @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14532k @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14509n @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14479resolve @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14643a @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14532k @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14503n @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14479resolve @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14643r @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:11883f @ dojo.js.uncompressed.js:11909
```

I'm including dojo using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

xhr Response:

```
"<!--Include Database connections info-->
```

↵
↵↵( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in E:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Weather-Widget-App-master\PHP\configHome.php on line *6*↵Call Stack↵#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation↵10.0004244528{main}( )..\weather.php**:**0↵20.0006248360include( 'E:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Weather-Widget-App-master\PHP\configHome.php' )..\weather.php**:**2↵30.0006248936http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect↵( )..\configHome.php**:**6↵↵
↵↵( ! ) Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in E:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Weather-Widget-App-master\PHP\configHome.php on line *9*↵Call Stack↵#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation↵10.0004244528{main}( )..\weather.php**:**0↵20.0006248360include( 'E:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Weather-Widget-App-master\PHP\configHome.php' )..\weather.php**:**2↵30.0300257280http://www.php.net/function.mysql-select-db' target='_new'>mysql_select_db↵( )..\configHome.php**:**9↵↵Error selecting specified database on mysql server: "

Comment: Does the xhr request receive a response? can you post it? I'm wondering if your server is returning malformed json.

Comment: Sounds like the server responds with XML not JSON

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did some further work and I found some helpful info in the xhr response (thanks Russell for your suggestion!).

Comment: Update: From the xhr response, i obviously had some errors with my SQL connection/statements. All fixed up now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was invalid/depreciated mysql. I rewrote my MYSQL with MYSQLi and everything fell into place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when returning a JSON from a service in which I previously var_dumped something. Uff. Hope it helps someone because I wasted 10 minutes to find the reason for that.